# Function that loops and create a JSON file in python not working

Tags: python, json, excel, python-2.7

I have a parsed an excel file and have a database in JSON style as below.

```
excel=[{'country': u'CH', 'product': u'MDF','scenario': u'BAU','year': 2010},
 {'country': u'CH', 'product': u'OSB', 'scenario': u'BAU','year': 2010},
 {'country': u'CH','product': u'MDF','scenario': u'BAU', 'year': 2011},
 {'country': u'CH', 'product': u'OSB', 'scenario': u'BAU','year': 2011},
 {'country': u'IT', 'product': u'MDF','scenario': u'BAU','year': 2010},
 {'country': u'IT', 'product': u'OSB', 'scenario': u'BAU','year': 2010},
 {'country': u'IT','product': u'MDF','scenario': u'BAU', 'year': 2011},
 {'country': u'IT', 'product': u'OSB', 'scenario': u'BAU','year': 2011}]

my_JSON={
    ('PEM_FORMIT', u'medium density fibreboard, at plant'): {
        'PEM_code': 'MDF',
         u'code': 245},
    ('PEM_FORMIT', u'oriented strand board, at plant'): {
        'PEM_code': 'OSB',
        u'code': 245}}
```

Basically I want to create another JSON that whenever 'product' in the excel is the same of 'PEM code' create another JSON, add a name and copy the relative object of 'my_json' and add other fields, like in the case below 'excel year' and 'excel country'. 
In this example should create a json with 8 instead of 2 object.

The function I wrote create the 8 JSON object with the proper name but it mess up all the other extra field to add (i.e. in this case 'excel country' and 'escel year') but the one 'excel product'.
Can you help me in undestanding why?

```
def myfunc(excel,my_JSON):
    empty_dict={}
    for rows in excel:
        if rows['scenario']=='BAU':
            for key,values in my_JSON.iteritems():
                if rows['product']==values['PEM_code']:
                    name_db="FORMIT_PEM_{}".format(rows['scenario']),"{} {} {}".format(rows['country'],rows['year'],rows['product'])
                    if name_db not in empty_dict:
                        empty_dict[name_db]=values 
                        empty_dict[name_db]['excel product']=rows['product'],
                        empty_dict[name_db]['excel year']=rows['year']
                        empty_dict[name_db]['excel country']=rows['country']



    return empty_dict
```

Return this that is wrong

```
{('FORMIT_PEM_BAU', 'CH 2010 MDF'): {'PEM_code': 'MDF',
  u'code': 245,
  'excel country': u'IT',    # should be CH
  'excel product': (u'MDF',),
  'excel year': 2011},       #should be 2010
 ('FORMIT_PEM_BAU', 'CH 2010 OSB'): {'PEM_code': 'OSB',
  u'code': 245,
  'excel country': u'IT',    # should be CH
  'excel product': (u'OSB',),
  'excel year': 2011},       # should be 2010
 ('FORMIT_PEM_BAU', 'CH 2011 MDF'): {'PEM_code': 'MDF',
  u'code': 245,
  'excel country': u'IT',    # should be CH
  'excel product': (u'MDF',),
  'excel year': 2011},
 ('FORMIT_PEM_BAU', 'CH 2011 OSB'): {'PEM_code': 'OSB',
  u'code': 245,
  'excel country': u'IT',    # should be CH
  'excel product': (u'OSB',),
  'excel year': 2011},
   .............
```

Where is the error?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi guys, sorry but I am a novice in posting here and do not have much experience in writing 'good' posts. Could you tell me what is wrong and what I should improve to avoid the same problem in the future?
Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the dictionaries of your `my_json`structure, and so you change afterwards the content of `empty_dict`. Instead you should make a copy:

```
def myfunc(excel,my_JSON):
    empty_dict={}
    for rows in excel:
        if rows['scenario']=='BAU':
            for key,values in my_JSON.iteritems():
                if rows['product']==values['PEM_code']:
                    name_db="FORMIT_PEM_{}".format(rows['scenario']),"{} {} {}".format(rows['country'],rows['year'],rows['product'])
                    if name_db not in empty_dict:
                        empty_dict[name_db] = dict(values) # copy 
                        empty_dict[name_db]['excel product']=rows['product'],
                        empty_dict[name_db]['excel year']=rows['year']
                        empty_dict[name_db]['excel country']=rows['country']



    return empty_dict
```